# Missing Reference in GitHub Project - ManagerIO_ConvertToTransfer - to Manager

Tags: c#, package

I've got this project from github [ManagerIO_ConvertToTransfer](https://github.com/niknah/ManagerIO_ConvertToTransfer)
 but when I run the solution it had missing assembly references:

- protobuf-net
- Manager

I have resolved the `protobuf-net` reference issue.

**I still haven't managed to fix the missing reference to `Manager`.**  I don't know where it came from.

I've tried to install it using `install-package Manager` but it says unable to find package.

The manager reference has this line of code.

```
using Manager;
using Manager.Model;
using Manager.Persistence;
```

Comment: Capitalize I's. Change the link to show project name. Reference List as a bullet points. Focused question on missing references. Removed [Manager] tag as its about bosses not the missing reference, c# because that is the language of the project